# Jquery scroll function to apply whenever page is reloaded when scrolling had already taken place before the reload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, scroll

I already know that I can use the `jQuery scroll()` method to apply a `scrolled` class to my navbar, which then allows me to do interesting things like change the background color of the navbar when the user scrolls down.

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var $nav = $("nav.fixed-top");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
});
```

This method fails however, when the user has already scrolled (and thereby applied the scrolled class), and then reloads the page. Immediately on reloading, there is no scroll class. It makes for some ugly looking UI.

How can I change this code such that whenever the page loads, it checks to see if the page is not at the top, and if it isn't, still applies the scrolled class? This way if the user scrolls to the middle and reloads the page, the browser is able to apply the `scrolled` class and therefore the appropriate css?

Examples:

1. [Image before scrolling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yGpP.png)
2. [Image of UI when scrolled class is added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMOP9.png)
3. [Image of UI when reloaded after scrolled class has applied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFgwf.png)

Answer (score 0):

While your page is loading (and you're scrolling), there's a great chance jQuery hasn't loaded yet, therefore the scroll event will not be triggered in your code.

You can get the number of pixels that the user has scrolled (after the page is loaded) using `$("html").scrollTop()`. If this is `0`, it means you're at the top of the page.

```js
$(document).scroll(function () {
    let $nav = $("nav.fixed-top");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
}).ready(function () {
    let $nav = $("nav.fixed-top");
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', $(this).scrollTop() > $nav.height());
});
```

The `.ready()` event will be triggered once the page loads.

Comment: This solved my problem. Once the page fully loads, it adds the class if you're not at the top of the page. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @EugeneNyawara Please feel free to mark my answer as accepted if this is the solution to your question. Selecting an accepted answer helps others with a similar problem to find the right solution

Answer (score 0):

On ready event you can check if user has scrolled

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    $nav.toggleClass('scrolled', 0 < $(window).scrollTop());
});
```